# Retrieve content from a database for a specific user

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am currently working on a Laravel project where I want the user to be able to upload various files then view their uploads.

Currently all users can see everyones uploads. Is there a way I can retrieve only the uploads for the user that is logged in?

I have attached images of my controller and blade.php below.

**blade.php**

View Files

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

        .wrapper{

            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 80%;
            margin-top: 10px;

        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>


    <div class="wrapper">

        <section class="panel panel-primary">

            <div class="panel-heading">

                <h2>  Uploads  </h2>

            </div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                <table class="table table-bordered">

                    <thead>

                        <th> User </th>
                        <th> Title </th>
                        <th> Upload Date & Time </th>
                        <th> Action </th>

                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                        @foreach($downloads as $down)


                        <tr>

                            <td> {{ Auth::user()->name }} </td>
                            <td> {{$down->name}} </td>
                            <td> {{$down->created_at}} </td>
                            <td> 

                            <a href="ftp://193.61.148.237//public_html/workspace/COM559/prototype/test/storage/app/public/upload/{{$down->name}}"download="{{$down->name}}"> 

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">

                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"> Download </i>

                            </button>

                            </a>

                            </td>

                        </tr>





                        @endforeach


                    </tbody>

                </table>

                </div>

        </section>

    </div>



</body>
```

**Controller file**

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  use DB;

  class Downloadcontroller extends Controller
  {


  public function downfunc() {


    $downloads=DB::table('files')->get();
    return view('download.viewfile', compact('downloads'));

        }
      }
```

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **Unfortunately, we can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$downloads = DB::table('files')->where('user_id', $userId)->get();`

or for current user you can:

`$downloads =  DB::table('files')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I'm pretty new to all this where would I put this code

Comment: @NiamhFlannery 18 line from your screenshot

Comment: so replace the current line I have?

Comment: @NiamhFlannery yes. Are you use auth? and what to get current authenticated user? then use 2nd variant

Comment: @NiamhFlannery for first variant you should find some user and then get it `id`

Comment: I replaced line 18 with what you have above but I got the error below:

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)"

Comment: @NiamhFlannery add `;` to the end

Comment: IT WORKED!! Thanks so much I've been working all day trying to get this. :) thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your database table has a column of `user_id`

You can fetch the data using this below function in your controller.

Hope this helps

```
public downfunc(){

    $downloads  =  DB::table('files')->where('user_id','=', $userId)->get();
    return view('download.viewfile',compact('downloads'));
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm pretty new to Laravel where would I put this code?

Comment: @NiamhFlannery in your controler

Comment: @laravellevaral you're missed comma near `=`, it's also not mandatory

Comment: also `$userId` is not defined in current function scope

Comment: @laravellevaral when I did the above I got the following error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'downfunc' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)"